# Connection id "{ConnectionId}" application never completed

Tags: asp.net-core

I have a ASP.NET Core 6 app that has been receiving periodically (once a day for ~10min) the fatal error `Connection id "{ConnectionId}" application never completed.` and I have no idea what this error is about.

The app is IDLE and still receiving the error.

It is running on 2 kubernetes clusters and I have already restarted the pods, but the problem keeps happening

The log info:

```
SourceContext: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel
messageTemplate: Connection id "{ConnectionId}" application never completed
level: Fatal
```

Does anyone knows what this error is about?